# Word for person who dreams big but does much bigger

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

What do you call a person who dreams big, but then does much bigger? In a good way, that is.

Comment: Do they do it on purpose? As in someone might dream of winning a lottery, and then win 3 in a row...

Comment: __Inspirational__. But that probably is not the word you're looking for.

Comment: How about lucky?

Comment: We don't do puzzles and guessing games here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Overachiever"**

> 1. one who achieves success over and above the standard or expected level
>      especially at an early age

(Merriam-Webster)

If you're looking for something that better captures the "dreams big" part, you might also try:

**"Wunderkind"**

> 1. a wonder child or child prodigy.
> 2. a person who succeeds, especially in business, at a comparatively early age.

(Merriam-Webster)

Perhaps some combination of the two?